# How to highlight two rows based on cell values Excel 2013

Tags: excel

I have 834,000+ rows of data in columns A-S. There are pairs of rows separated by a blank row. For each pair, I need to compare column S in both rows and if they both contain "Y", then I need both rows highlighted. If they don't match, then no action is taken. How can I set this up so that it skips the blank rows and highlights the pairs correctly?

Comment: Define "pair" .. how do you know they are a "pair" ?  Is there a key column? ie the value in A matches ? or just look at the first non-blank row above and below it ??

Comment: Or is the data like `"YY<blank>YY<blank>YN<blank>NN<blank> ... etc"` ??

Comment: They have been matched for our purposes using criteria within the rows. There are always two rows followed by a blank.

Comment: Ok, thought so (I think I understood that - finally - after the third read of your initial post ;) )  Check my answer below

Comment: The fields can be any combination of Y and N. I only want to highlight the rows were both are Y. There are always two rows followed by a blank.

Comment: Thanks for your perseverance, Ditto. How does your resolution account for the blank rows? For instance, row 1 is the header row, rows 2 and 3 are the first pair, and row 4 is the first blank row. So I need to skip row 4 and have the formula next compare rows 5 and 6.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula in cell T10 : `=AND(S10="Y",OR(S10=S9,S10=S11))`  then copy it up and down. If that shows TRUE for the rows you want to highlight .. you can now easily setup a conditional format for the range, based on Column T. ;)